# How to find all duplicates within a line and put it into one cell with a line break?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to search for a specific value (with wildcards – for example "car") within a line (A1-C1). I have no header – only this line. In this line the value can appear in multiple columns. How can I get all findings in one cell (A3) with a line break?

```
A1                    | B1              | C1       
Carsharing Car        | Bicycle         | Boot with a Car

A3
Carsharing Car (line break)
Boot with a Car
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Hey @player0 again :) I unfortunately can share this sheet because of security causes. I know that doesnt help :/ I specific my answer in the original post. Maybe this can help you more to understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10); 1, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(1:1; "(?i)car"); 1:1; )))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Ok, now I have an extra question. Can you tell me why the IFERROR doesnt work here?  `=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10); 1, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(1:1; "(?i)car"); 1:1; ))); "Not Found")`